Doubts about some problems concerning comparability of infinitesimals?
I'm reading Efimov's Higher Mathematics. There is this definition:



After that, there are several problems with some proofs, computational exercises, etc. And then, there are the following problems:



I'm a bit confused: Am I expected to employ the concept of infinitesimals to computer this somehow? If it is, It's not clear to me how to do it.

No, you are just supposed to use the linear approximation to the appropriate function ($\frac1{x}$, $\sqrt{x}$, $x^5$,  $x^4$).

I imagine that the envisioned applications involve the analysis of algorithms, in which such asymptotic behavior is a basic building block. Check out ideas like $O(f(x))$ and $o(f(x))$, referred to as big-O and little-o notation, respectively. And similarly, $\Theta(f(x))$ and $\theta(f(x))$. And, while we’re at it, $\Omega(f(x))$ and $\omega(f(x))$ too.
